# Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid string value (arg="x", coderType="string", value=5)

Tags: truffle, react, compiler

Using `Truffle unbox react` to unbox a boilerplate.

received the following error from running `npm run start`

Changes:

- Addition of `"memory"` parameters in the simpleStorage.sol
- Changed `unit` to `string` in the simpleStorage.sol
- Adjusted port address to `"7545"` to match Ganache's port.
- Changed `truffle-config` to `truffle.js` for mac

Other than those changes, the boilerplate is still pretty much barebones.

Attempts for a solution:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled `-g` and `local` truffle
- Attempted multiple solutions for pragma requiring specific compiler to no avail. <- (I am sure this is probably the problem. However, me not being able to find this error searching all day tells me it could be something else before I even get to that.)
- Attempted brew re-installation & updates from solc docs.
- Updated Ganache to latest v.
- Attempted `optimizer` & `versions` properties suggested for the compiler object in truffle.js.
- Attempted complete wipes and resets and following the documentations for `truffle unbox react` documentation's step by step instead of other guides.

I would post the code, but literally re-attempting from a clean slate 3-4 times with most of these methods repeatedly already labels this code as barebones besides the subtle changes I listed.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this after having the latest Truffle framework and Solidity I did the following:

- I had to manually update pragma versions for the default `truffle unbox react` .sol files.
- Create a compiler object within the `truffle.js` (mac) or `truffle-config.js` (Windows naming convention.) for version control.
- Make sure to check JSON files for compiler versions. I double check after creating a compiler object for the truffle configuration to make sure. (Its a bit extra, but all considerations of the support on this growing industry.)

Apart of the big confusion here to beware of is plug-ins. `VS Code Solidity`

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity

I will have to get on gitter to inform him of the possible bug too. Beware as well other solidity plug-ins sometimes mentions a fork off of Juan Blanco's original plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your App.js is attempting to set an int value to your storage variable which you changed to a string type.

In App.js change line 42 so that your contract.methods.set() call sets a string not an Int.q

Also should edit how storageValue is defined in the state definition in App.js from storageValue: 0 to storageValue: ""